# In `ggforce/geom_parallel_sets_labels`, how to add more information to the bar label

Tags: r, ggforce

In `ggforce/geom_parallel_sets_labels` , how to add the person count number to the black bar ? Thanks! (Below code use data Titanic, and want to show person count number in the bar )

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

data <- reshape2::melt(Titanic)
data <- gather_set_data(data, 1:4)

ggplot(data, aes(x, id = id, split = y, value = value)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = Sex), alpha = 0.3, axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(colour = 'white')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `after_stat` to alter the default label and add e.g. the counts from the `value` column like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

data <- reshape2::melt(Titanic)
data <- gather_set_data(data, 1:4)

ggplot(data, aes(x, id = id, split = y, value = value)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = Sex), axis.width = 0.3, alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = 0.3) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(aes(label = after_stat(paste(label, value, sep = "\n"))), colour = 'white')
```

[image]

**UPDATE** When using `after_stat` you only have access to the processed data, i.e. the data after it was processed by `ggplot2` or `ggforce`, and only the variables which are contained in the this data, e.g. only variables which mapped on aesthetics are present in this data. Hence, the `value_p` column you added to the data is not available via `after_stat`. One option to fix that would be to add this column inside `after_stat` for which I use a custom helper function:

```
helper_after_stat <- function(x, value, label) {
  data.frame(x = x, value = value, label = label) %>% 
    group_by(x) %>% 
    mutate(value_p = value / sum(value),
           label = paste(label, value, scales::percent(value_p), sep = "\n")) %>%
    pull(label)
}

ggplot(data, aes(x, id = id, split = y, value = value)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = Sex), axis.width = 0.3, alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = 0.3) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(aes(label = after_stat(helper_after_stat(x, value, label))), colour = 'white')
```

[image]

Comment: if i want to add value and weight percent to chart below code failed. Could you help to take a look ? Thanks !    @stefan   library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)

data <- reshape2::melt(Titanic)
data <- gather_set_data(data, 1:4)
data0 <- data %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(value_p = value/sum(value))

ggplot(data0, aes(x, id = id, split = y, value = value)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = Sex), axis.width = 0.3, alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = 0.3) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(aes(label = after_stat(paste(label, value, value_p,sep = "\n"))), colour = 'white')

Comment: See my update on how to achieve that.

Comment: it's greate  Thanks for your help !